# Ways to Find Multivariable Taylor Polynomial at non zero point

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If I were to find the 4th order Taylor polynomial of $$f(x,y) = ye^x$$ at a point ($a$,0) for non-zero $a$, is it possible to use single variable Taylor polynomial expression of $e^x$?

For $a=0$ it is easy, take $e^x \approx 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}$.

Thus $ye^x \approx  y(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}) \approx y(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3!})$, where the last step takes us to the desired 4th order Taylor polynomial.

However, for $a \neq 0 $, I am running into this trouble: if we are finding the single variable Taylor polynomial at a center that is not zero, the expression will contain $x-a$.

For example, at $(1,0)$:
$e^x \approx e+ e(x-1) + \frac{e}{2}(x-1)^2+\frac{e}{3!}(x-1)^3 + \frac{e}{4!}(x-1)^4 $

But the $(x-1)^4$ has lower order terms, and so does $(x-1)^5, (x-1)^6, ...$ etc.

**Question:**
Does this mean the only way to compute the 4th order Taylor polynomial of this function at $(1,0)$ is to calculate the all the 4th order partial derivatives? Is there still a way to do it with single variable taylor polynomials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is correct. The Taylor polynomial of order 4 at a point $(x_0,y_0)$ is of degree $4$ **in the variables $h=x-x_0$ and $k=y-y_0$**. At $(1,0)$ in your example, you retain the terms which are of degree up to $4$ in $(x-1)$ and $y$, so you multiply $y$ by the polynomial of degree $3$ of $f(x)=e^x$ centered at $x=1$ and you are done.

Comment: Why is it that you're multiplying $y$ by the third order Taylor polynomial of $e^x$? Aren't you then missing some terms then in the expansion of the y(x-1)^4 term? (For example, -4x^3y + 6x^2y -4xy + y). These terms are all degree less than 4.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying, I should view the taylor polynomial of $e^x$ centered at 1 as: $e+ eh + \frac{e}{2}h^2+\frac{e}{3!}h^3 + \frac{e}{4!}h^4$, where $h=x-1$ and only keep track of $h^my^n$ terms such that $m+n \leq 4$, correct?

Comment: That is correct.